# How to know the colour of a certain point in the canvas in flutter custom painter?

Tags: flutter, custom-painting

I am making a painter program and I want know the colour of a point when tapping on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this package: [`pixel_color_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/pixel_color_picker).